# Convert request input containing emoji in PHP and saving in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, emoji

I have php script that takes user's text from

```
$_REQUEST['comment_text']
```

And saves it into MySQL database using MySQLi.

```
$comment_text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['comment_text']);
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO comments (text) VALUES ('$comment_text')");
```

Everything is working as expected. But I have problems when there are emojis in user's input. My comments table has CHARSET=utf8 and I need to leaved it in this way.

So if I want to store emojis I have to store them this way

> "\ud83d\ude09"

But how should I handle user's input in this case?

Comment: how do they arrive in `$_REQUEST['comment_text']`?

Comment: my script is receiving them form POST request

Comment: no Jeff means in what format do they arrive within that variable?

Comment: maybe I don't understand something, it is simply string that I am taking from request. I can simulate this request in Postman.

Comment: yes. What does the string look like. literaly. When you `echo $_REQUEST['comment_text']`. Is it `"\ud83d\ude09"`? Is it `"????"`?

Comment: There's a lot of possibilities but they usually boil down to character encodings.  Everything has to use the same encoding and the encoding has to support emoji.  This implies unicode and more specifically UTF8.  Your code needs to be in UTF8, your connection to the DB needs to be in UTF8 and your database needs to be in UTF8 (or UTF8MB4 for MySQL because their original UTF8 implementation was broken).  Also you might want to consider using prepared statements instead of string escaping.  It's safer and it's possible that escaping has issues with emoji that prepare doesn't.

Comment: Not sure what's not to understand. You say you need to store emojis in the format mentioned. So...at the moment what is preventing you from doing that? Is there a problem with what is being sent by the browser? That's why we're asking you to show that data

Comment: That seems to be two Unicode "code points", but invalid ones.  What character(s) were you expecting?